# Predicting football teams from images

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, feature-engineering, supervised-learning

**Background**

Given a set of images of different sports and players from different teams.

The task is to identify if the image depicts a football match. I have tried the Watson Visual Recognition and it can do this with a good accuracy upto certain extend. To identify which team is there in the image, using the color of the Jersey, what could be a suitable algorithm that could be used?

And is there a set of training data that is publicly available?

The question is mostly looking for recommendations. And I am not sure if this is the right  place for the question to be asked.